# cannot select/unselect angular-ui bootstrap checkbox

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am using angular-ui bootstrap in my project. I use navigation bar, carousel, dropdowns etc. without problem. However checkbox html code doesn't work. I cannot click on checkbox to select/unselect. I am using bootstrap v3.3.6 and angularjs v1.5.5

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label class="pull-left">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="accept"> I Accept Terms&Conditions
   </label>
</div>
```

If I remove class="checkbox" from div checkbox works fine.

Comment: Do you have custom CSS on the .checkbox class?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://scotch.io/tutorials/handling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-in-angular-forms